# How to access Mule Message properties in jersey component

Tags: java, jersey, mule

I am using the Jersey module, Can anybody tell me how to access the mule message properties from within a jersey component?

I need to have access to one of the objects stored in the message properties.

Comment: Hmm.. I might be "far out" with regards to what you're doing here, but in the single project I worked with Mule, we instantiated Jersey components as Spring beans. In that case it was just a matter of injecting the property you want as a spring property.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the source code and, at least in 3.3.1, it doesn't appear the Mule injects any custom `@Context`, which could have including the `MuleEvent` (this the message and its properties).

So the only thing I can think of is to use the **deprecated** static accessor to the in-flight event: `org.mule.RequestContext.getEvent()`.

MuleSoft may remove it any time though so this is not future proof. Hopefully, when they'll drop it, they'll also provide a replacement that can be used in JAX-RS resources.